# this product key cannot be used to convert to + Sharepoint 2013 + Project Server 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, project-server, license

I need suggestion to find a solution..

I have the next enviroment's configuration

- Windows Server 2012
- Sharepoint 2013
- Project Server 2013

And we have the product key for sharepoint 2013.. but when we trying to register, we have two problems

1 - The text field and button "ok" are locked. To solve this, we find a "trick".. not sure if is the correct way, then we open the developper tools in the brownser and we remove the property disabled to unlock it. It works, but!!

2 - After to remove the property and enter the product key.. then click "ok" we have the next message:

This product key cannot be used to convert to

We think that maybe we have to activate it using a Project Server 2013 product key, but not sure..

What do you think? Project server overwrite the sharepoint license?

Comment: what's the current license, what is  SharePoint edition Is it standard or enterprise?

Comment: Hi @M.Qassas we have a trial Enterprise license.. thats show me in the Enable Enterprise Features secction.

Comment: @M.Qassas did you have a similar situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Project Server binaries installed in your farm then you will require a SharePoint **Enterprise** license as well as a Project Server license. As for registering the license you only need to register the Project Server one, that's from memory as it's been a few months at least since my last install and longer since I installed 2013.

You can test this quickly by using a trial license if you can find one, the following TechNet link has a 2016 trial license which I guess will not work in your case.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37674.project-server-2016-configuration.aspx#Enable_Project_Server_License

Either way the solution is to get a Project Server 2013 license.

PS. Cool hack, but yeah *nice try*. :)

Comment: Thanks you for your comment!!! I guess that I have to get a Project Server license.

Comment: unfortunately the serial key of Project server cannot activate Sharepoint.. :/ What can I do?

Comment: Project Server requires a SharePoint Enterprise license as well, so I guess my memory is wrong and you need to enter the SharePoint Enterprise key first and then the PS one.

Comment: But what do you think about the text field locked? there is a trial version that cannot be activated?

Comment: I'm not sure which field you refer to being locked. Is this in Central Admin where you add licenses?

Comment: That is, in the Convert License Type section within the Central Administration, is disabled.